# Read Excel file with OleDB c#, when it is used by other process

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read an excel file every 2 seconds, This file is getting updated by other RTD application.

I am able to read this file by Oledb connection, but problem comes when i am trying to read it every 2 seconds. Out of 10 attempts it is able to read 4-5 times only and at other attempts ,it throws exception.

**Connection String**

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\nids\shes.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
```

**Code**

```
//opening connection to excel file

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(constr))//constr = connection string
{
    try
    {  
        connection.Open();
        isconopen = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        dispatcherTimer2.Start();

        connection.Close();
        isconopen = false;
    }

    // If connection is ok , then query sheet  
    if (isconopen == true)
    {
        strcon = "SELECT * FROM [" + dsheet + "]";

        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strcon, connection))
        {

            try
            {


                adapter.Fill(result);
                isread = true;
                adapter.Dispose();

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch 
            {

                isread = false;
                dispatcherTimer2.Start();

                adapter.Dispose();
                connection.Close();

            }

        }
     }

    //if able to retrieve data then call some other function 
    if (isread == true)
    {
        converToCSV(0);// for further processing
    }
```

Please help me , i am trying this from last 1 month. Please please please please help me out

Comment: Well, what do you need to get? Can't you simply catch the exception and **retry** after (let's say) 500 msec? If this is not viable you may simply make a copy with File.Copy then **open the copy**. Sadly you can't ask OleDB driver to share file between instances.

Comment: @Adriano,First of all thanks for giving ur time,I am doing same retry but looking for some better way, Problem in copying file is data of file is not getting saved on hard disk. This excel file is open on computer. Can you please share me code / way where i can save/copysave that file every 2 seconds and then read that file

Comment: I would definitely follow the @Adriano suggestion in his reply to use a FileSystemWatcher

Answer (score 7):

Sadly OleDB driver by default will open file exclusively then you can't open it when it's in use by someone else, even just for reading.

Two considerations:

- Other application may finalize its work with the file within milliseconds so it's good to try again
- Driver will always open file locked for writing (so you can't open it twice via OleDB) but it's shared for reading (so you can copy it).

That said I suggest you should first try to open it after a short pause, if it's still in use (and you can't wait more) then you can make a copy and open that.

Let me assume you have your code in a `HandlExcelFile()` function:

```
void HandleExcelFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        // Function will perform actual work
        HandleExcelFileCore(path); 
    }
    catch (Exception) // Be more specific
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100); // Arbitrary

        try
        {
            HandleExcelFileCore(path);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            File.Copy(path, tempPath);

            try
            {
                HandleExcelFileCore(tempPath);
            }
            finally
            {
                File.Delete(tempPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code is little bit ugly so just consider it a starting point to write your own function.

Considerations:

- Retry isn't such bad thing and it's a common way to solve this kind of problems. It's, for example, what Windows shell does (and it's even more normal with networks).
- If application didn't close the file then you may copy (and read) *old* data. If you always need most up-to-date data then you have only one choice: wait. If you can assume that unsaved data belongs to the previous time frame (T - 1, as in digital electronic when signal edge is on clock edge) then just do it and live happy.

Untested solution:

I didn't try this so you have to do it by yourself. Actuallly (I was initially wrong) you can open a read-only connection (through extended properties). It's not documented if this apply to connection only or both file handle and connection. Anyway let's try to change your connection string to:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\nids\shes.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=true"
```

Just added a `ReadOnly=true` at the end of `Extended Properties`.

Other solutions:

- The only alternative solution that comes to my mind is to...manually read Excel file (so you can open it just for reading). That said even in this case the other application may have not written new data (so you'll read *old* one).
- Don't use a timer at all. Change your design to use a `FileSystemWatcher`, you'll read the file only when notified it has been changed.
- When applicable...just do not use a shared file as IPC mechanism! Well, you may not be able to change 2nd application so this may not be your case.
- Do not use OleDB to read Microsoft Excel files, there are many 3rd part free libraries that don't open file with exclusive lock, for example [this one](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).
- Do not read data directly from files, if Microsoft Excel instance is always running you can use COM interop to get notifications. Check [this general article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291392/en-us) about COM add-ins and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126/en-us) to see how you can attach your C# application with Office Interop to an existing Microsoft Excel instance.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, FileSystemWatcher could be best option but here scenario is totally different, This excel file is getting updated by some DDE (RTD) **but it does not save excel file** instead it just update values in excel cells which we can see / read manually

Comment: Dear All one of major hurdle is whenever data is updated in this excel, **it does not saved on hard disk(if we try to read data from file stream then it gives old data which can be 2 hours or more old)**, i have tried 10s of ways and found that only OleDB is able to read unsaved data from Excel file

Comment: I have already tried this ReadOnly = True, but result is same :(

Comment: @NidhiSharma interesting! I performed a quick search and...most common suggestion was to do not use OleDB for that. If it works for you may give a try to http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks a lot for all your efforts , Actually i am stucked in this problem from last one month and tried all these resources, it also read only data which is saved on hard disk and can not read unsaved data. I guess i have to drop this project now :(

Comment: @NidhiSharma If they're running on the same machine...did you try **COM interop** too (or maybe even an **add-in**)?

Comment: Yes both of them are running on same machine , can you give me little bit idea or link for  COM interop too (or maybe even an add-in), i have not tried them since do not have much knowledge about them but have good learning aptitude, if you show me way i will reach destination , thanks in advance

Comment: @NidhiSharma [read this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291392/en-us) for a general introduction to COM add-ins. Try [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126/en-us), it works even if little bit old, to see how to attach to a running Excel instance.

Comment: Adding the Read only attribute worked for me when I was getting the dialog _"<File name> is now available for editing. Choose Read-Write to open it for editing."_ After adding this property the Excel process was killed as expected and didn't hang around chewing up memory until I killed it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure , why do you want to read the excel the way you are doing.

You can try [LinqToExcel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) for excel reading , its a nice little library for reading excel files also  if you need to create excel then try to  [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library. These library i personally found really effective when working with Excels

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Below fixes worked for me

1) Don't hold your connection to sheet. Instead open connection read data and close the connection immediately.

2) If you are using managed code in the unmanaged application then consider using object of managed type instead of pointer(using gcnew) and use [Stack Semantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx) to make sure that memory is cleaned up when object goes out of scope.