# OleDBException when reading an open excel file

Tags: c#, excel, file, adapter

I have an excel file and an `oledb` connection to it. When reading data while file is opened in windows, it throws the following error (at `Adapter.Fill` method).

**However, the code runs fine when file is not opened manually.**

```
private System.Data.DataSet GetExcelData()
{
    // Create new DataSet to hold information from the worksheet.
    System.Data.DataSet objDataset1 = new System.Data.DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelFilePath"];
        //string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        objConn.Open();

        //String strConString = "SELECT * FROM [Data Version5.2$A2:ZZ] where [Status] = 'aa'";//Status
        String strConString = "SELECT * FROM [Data Version5.2$A2:ZZ] where [Status] IS NULL OR [Status]='SubReport'";//Status SubReport

        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(strConString, objConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        // Pass the Select command to the adapter.  
        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;

        // Fill the DataSet with the information from the work sheet.
        objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "ExcelData");

        objConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return objDataset1;
}
```

The error message is

[image]

Comment: `However, the code runs fine when file is not opened manually.` possible duplicate of [Read Excel file with OleDB c#, when it is used by other process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798948/read-excel-file-with-oledb-c-when-it-is-used-by-other-process)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes, Sid's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to write to the file, try adjusting your connection string to include the read only mode (`Mode=Read`). I have that in all of mine (where I don't need to write to the file) and I've never had a problem reading from workbooks that are already open:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
    path + ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
```

I also don't tend to read Excel files as XML, so the Extended Properties for my connection strings are `Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;`