# C# Opening SQL Connection from Currently Opened Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Can somebody help me regarding the problem I encountered in C# and Excel.
Currently, my code goes like this:

```
string fname = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
```

`con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fname + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + hdr + "\""`);

I am trying to connect to Excel worksheet as my database from my C# application. 
What bother's me is that, when the workbook or my database (**fname**) in the connection string above is currently open or when the **con.Open()** method is invoked, the application opens a **readonly** copy of the path, How could I prevent this?

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt you can - Excel's default behaviour is to only allow one writeable version of the file

Comment: @stuartd Yes, it should be one instance only. But when I try to connect to the currently opened workbook to perform a query, however, Excel open a readonly copy of the same workbook. It causes me an error, and want to prevent it. :(

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798948/read-excel-file-with-oledb-c-when-it-is-used-by-other-process

Comment: If so, how could I perform a SELECT query in an existing or opened workbook?

Comment: Ian,
Are you open to using any other methods of reading the sheet? You could read the range of cells you want without having to go through the ole db 
connection issues,

Comment: Hi @dgorti . Thank you, If so, how? :)